# Why does a manual mount set different file ownership?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mount, automounting

I've been using the terminal for almost everything: in fact, I often don't even log in through the interface, I use the `tty1` and go to the web with text-browsers. So, the external drive doesn't auto-mount, and I use `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/JMCF125_DE` to mount it. It works, but listing shows there's a difference. The files' description when auto-mounting via the GUI (Unity on Ubuntu) looks like:

```
-rw------- 1 jmcf125 jmcf125
```

In manual mount, the same files' properties look like this:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root
```

Which makes sense since I had to use `sudo` to mount. But how come the system doesn't have to? How can my mounts work exaclty like the systems'? Also, I heard every action in the GUI goes through a background shell: can I see what commands are printed there?

Comment: Your GUI is passing different options to mount. It may be using a front-end such as pmount. What GUI do you normally use? Under what distribution?

Comment: @Gilles, Unity under Ubuntu 12.04 x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default GUI uses [Gvfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gvfs) to mount removable drives and other dynamic filesystems. Gvfs requires [D-Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus). You can launch D-Bus outside of an X11 environemnt, but [it's tricky](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44317/reuse-d-bus-sessions-across-login-sessions). If you have D-Bus running, you can make gvfs mounts from the command line with [gvfs-mount](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gvfs-mount.1.html).

The program `pmount` provides a convenient way to mount removable drives without requiring `sudo`. Pmount is setuid root, so it can mount whatever it wants, but it only allows a whitelist of devices and mount points so it can safely be called by any user.

It is not true that every action in the GUI goes through a background shell. A few do but most don't.

Comment: Thanks, I installed `pmount`, and it works. Can I add permissions for normal users to mount removable drives in other locations rather than `/media` (as long as they own those and they're empty)? Or for that do I have to use the tricky way?

Comment: @JMCF125 I don't think pmount allows this. There's no fundamental reason why it doesn't, except that I think it's tricky to do without a race condition. FUSE allows that, but it works differently under the hood.