# Can I automate mounting a cifs share without storing my password in plaintext?

Tags: security, rhel, mount, password, automounting

I currently use a script which contains commands along the lines of

```
sudo /sbin/mount.cifs $SERVER_SHARE $MOUNT -o username=$DOMAIN_$USER,uid=$USER,gid=$USER,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775
```

to mount my cifs shared directories. This works fine, but I have to enter my password for each of these lines, so I would like to automate this process.

In order to adhere to local security policy I must not add my password to the command line, nor may I store my password in plain text in a file (either the mount script or a credentials file).

Do I have any other options for authenticating my cifs mount, or am I stuck entering my password for each and every share?

Ideally I would like the equivalent of doing a `ssh-add`, where I only have to enter my password once and all subsequent `ssh` commands use that authentication and do not require me to enter my password again.

If it makes any difference, I am using [RHEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) 5.8 as a normal user with very limited sudo access.

Answer (score 4):

The [Gnome keyring](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring) can store passwords. You can enter the password in your Gnome keyring, or if you use the Gnome keyring for other things, you can put a master password and save the keyring to disk.

[GVFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS), the Gnome virtual filesystem framework, queries the Gnome keyring for passwords if it's available.

From the command line, you can perform a Samba mount with `gvfs-mount`:

```
gvfs-mount smb://username\;workgroupname@hostname/sharename
```

You have no control on the mount point: it's `~/.gvfs/sharename\ on\ hostname`. And I don't think that you can control mount options such as permission mappings (but I could be wrong: `gvfs-mount` is not documented and I haven't explored its internals).

You'll need D-bus. See [Samba mount with password prompt as non-root user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44127/samba-mount-with-password-prompt-as-non-root-user/44318#44318)

Comment: Thanks Gilles, sadly it looks like `gvfs-mount` isn't available on my RHEL 5.8 machine, so I'll have to talk to I.T. about getting it installed. I'll update my question.

Comment: On Ubuntu MATE 22.10, it mounts to /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=SERVERNAME,share=SHARENAME instead of under ~/.gvfs .  (1000 is my user ID, yours might be different)