# Automate a mount without linux password to mount a remote cifs filesystem

Tags: debian, mount, cifs

I have a directory in my Debian home: /home/myuser/pchome/ which i want to use as a mount point for a remote cifs filesystem. So i have a bash script, which is run on every myuser login. This script contains the command:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.1.2/myuser -o username=myuser,password=mypassword,uid=1000,gid=1000 /home/myuser/pchome
```

The command works like a charm using itself in a console. But, the problem is that mount requires sudo and password introduction (or be run with root privileges).

**sudoers**

First approach i thought about is configure the sudoers to allow the use of mount for myuser. Something like:

```
myuser ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: /bin/mount, /bin/umount
```

The problem with that, is that myuser could use mount without limits, even for mounting filesystems on /etc, for example. I'm not interested in allowing myuser the use of mount command freely.

**fstab**

Second approach i thought about, is using fstab to allow the mount. I did not test it, but i think that, with this solution, both the mount point and filesystem to mount could be fixed, and no other mount could be done. But, every user could perform the mount (if using the "user" option for fstab line).

From my point of view, none of the two ideas is correct enought, so i would like if any of you knows the valid approach to that problem.
I only want to be allowed to mount a public remote filesystem using a mount point inside my home without any concern about security, passwords or exposing the system to malicious mounts. It should be easier, since the mount point is inside my own home.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can specify mount privileges per user in fstab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82194/proper-way-to-mount-samba-share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to save the mounting command as a script (modifiable only by root) AND define sudo privileges for the script.

`/home/bin/mymount`:

```
#!/bin/sh
mount -t cifs //192.168.1.2/myuser -o username=myuser,password=mypassword,uid=1000,gid=1000 /home/myuser/pchome
```

`sudoers`:

```
myuser ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: /home/bin/mymount # and maybe , /home/bin/myumount
```

As a sidenote, you may also want to save that CIFS password in a [credentials file](/home/bin/mymount).

---

You can give the permission to various users by defining an alias or by giving the permission to a group.

Using an alias:

```
User_Alias CIFSUSERS = myuser, user2, user3 #, more users
CIFSUSERS ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: /home/bin/mymount # ...
```

Or giving permission to a group, e.g. group `floppy`:

```
%floppy ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: /home/bin/mymount # ...
```

Comment: It's a good alternative. Although it seems not very scalable (adding one line to sudoers per each user, for example), it's cleaner than giving full access to mount command. Thanks.

Comment: @AlbertoJiménez actually, the `sudoers` file is quite flexible. You don't need to add a new rule for every user. You can use user aliases or give permission to a group. I've updated my answer to show both possibilities.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot, @outlyer. giving permission to a newly created group sounds very clean and simple. Incredibly, i didn't realize that i could use a group, although i'm currently using that option for sudo and dialer groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [autofs](https://www.howtoforge.com/accessing_windows_or_samba_shares_using_autofs)

In that way when user access the folder it will be automatically mounted.