# Mounting a shared drive on CentOS

Tags: centos, mount, gvfs

I am trying to mount a shared drive on my CentOS PC. However, when I run

```
gvfs-mount smb://the.server.address/path_on_server
```

I get the error `Error mounting location: Failed to mount Windows share: No such file or directory` and running the same command with sudo gives `Error mounting location: volume doesn't implement mount`.

I also appear not to have a `gvfs` directory. After looking into the problem I found suggestions saying`gvfs-fuse` package was required. I tried installing the package and adding myself to the fuse group (after creating it) but the same error still occurs. I haven't found anything about this specifically for CentOS - all my other seaches return Ubuntu solutions for similar but ultimately different problems.

Comment: Why not just use mount -t cifs?

Comment: The initial instruction from our IT department was to use the command I gave. I'll have a try with your suggestion

Comment: At a minimum, the syntax will be something like mount -t cifs //fileserver/desired/path /mount/point -o <various options, for example: username=<domain account>,domain=<domain name>>

Comment: @JesseKeilson I just tried mount cifs and I get the error `mount error(6): No such device or address`

Comment: Sounds like your //fileserver/desired/path is off.

Comment: @JesseKeilson A trip to IT support it is then

Comment: I agree with Jessie Kielson, mount is much easier. But you have to be root. You can also add the mount to /etc/fstab (it must be in fstab format) and the share will be mounted automatically at boot. You can also check what cifs shares are offered by a host with the command : `smbclient -L ip.address -U username` (you can use hostname also instead of IP address)

Answer (score 2):

I think You'll find the answer here:
[Samba mount with password prompt as non-root user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44127/samba-mount-with-password-prompt-as-non-root-user)

For me, after exporting dbus-launch values, the gvfs-mount did not give error anymore :

```
export $(dbus-launch)
gvfs-mount smb://workgroupname\;username@hostname/sharename
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - unfortunately I am getting exactly the same error still.

Comment: Actually, I now get asked for username, domain and password - and the it says `Error mounting location: Failed to mount Windows share: No such file or directory`. I don't suppose you know what could cause that?

Comment: I had to install some packages too...like gvfs-smb. Also, i can only browse the mounted stuff in the graphical interface, don't know yet how to use it in the terminal. I also created a folder `/root/fuse` and used the `gvfsd-fuse /root/fuse`command. In order to avoid asking password, I had to disable in Windows this feature (rightclick network icon, open network and sharing center/change advanced sharing settings/in All networks Turn off password protected sharing)