# mounting smb shares without root permission

Tags: mount, smb

How do I mount network shares without root? It has been discussed a lot but I found no useful answers (`sudo` not acceptable, `fstabs` not acceptable, `mount.cifs` does not work without root either).

The issue is, `Dolphin` (KDE file manager) or `Krusader` can mount e.g. USB drives without requiring me to be a root as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62676/mounting-from-dolphin-vs-commandline). But it cannot be used for network shares. Is there any similar approach for `smb` shares?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gvfs-mount`:

```
gvfs-mount smb://user@server/storage
```

Depending on the version and OS, you can then find the mounted storage below `~/.gvfs` or `/run/user/$UID/gvfs`

---

Related:

- [Samba mount with password prompt as non-root user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44127/samba-mount-with-password-prompt-as-non-root-user)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get `/etc/fstab` mounts to work without sudo, but then you will have problems with the username.

I can have a

```
//<some-server>/data$/smbshares/Cluster /mnt/Dfs/Cluster cifs user,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmv2,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,nounix,noauto,_netdev 0 0
```

entry in fstab, and I can then do a user mount as

```
mount -v -v /mnt/Dfs/Cluster/
```

and it will also ask for a password when mounting

```
Password for myuser@//<some-server>/data$/smbshares/Cluster:
```

But it will now mount the SMB remote with my login username. 
Now, my username and the username for the SMB may not be equal,
and here is the main problem: I could specify a `-o` option for the user mount as

```
mount -v -v /mnt/Dfs/Cluster/ -o user=mysambauser1231
```

but it seems this local `user=name`
clashes with the needed `user` options in the fstab entry. 
Trying different modes of the `--options-mode`

```
mount /mnt/Dfs/Cluster/ -o user=au204573 --options-mode append
```

did not work for me (I tried `append`, `prepend`, and `replace`).  So I am not able to mount as a user with an SMB username different than the current username.

(But hardcoding the SMB username in the fstab works,
à la `user,user=mysambauser1231,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmv2,..`!)